# Sparklines – how to construct an average per months to compare performance

Tags: reporting-services

I need to build a Tablix with a sparkline comparing each employee’s performance with the average per employee. All measures are limited via parameters for a number of months in one year compared with Same Period Last Year via MDX measures.

The Tablix has a column group per month and a row group per staff_id. The rows at the bottom (below the sparklines) are summary rows without row groups. 
I wanted to post a Picture, but I am unable due to lack of reputation. So I hope that you are able to understand the Tablix structure from the text above.

When building the sparkline I have two measures. 1st is a line representing the MeasureX for a given employee. 2nd should be an areas for “Avg. MeasureX per Employee” but I cannot figure out how to get the correct scope.

My broken code:

```
=(Sum(Fields!No_MeasureX.Value, "Tablix12") / CountDistinct(Iif(Fields!No_MeasureX.Value >0, Fields!Staff_Id.Value, Nothing), "Tablix12"))
```

The broken code is currently scoped for the whole tablix, which provides an average over all the months. I need an average per month.

The IIF is necessary because there are empty rows in the dataset.

I have constructed the “Avg. X per Employee” correctly outside the row group (close to the bottom of the tablix) with the code below:

```
=Sum(Fields!No_MeasureX.Value) / CountDistinct(Iif(Fields!No_MeasureX.Value >0, Fields!Staff_Id.Value, Nothing))
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the default scope e.g. delete `, "Tablix12"`.  Otherwise use the Group Name for the Employee group.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for the reply. If I use either the default scope or "Staff_id1" (Employee Group) then I get a value of 1 per month in the sparklines. This makes sense, since the row Group seperate employees on one line each. What I need is a sum of all Unique staff_ids for a given month.

Comment: Whats the scope of the sparkline?  Is it within the month column group?

Comment: No. The sparkline is only within the row Group "Staff_Id". The Month column Group is in a column on the right side (outside) to show detailed information.